# Removing unique key in mysql and retain the field

Tags: mysql, sql

Am using a mysql database and i would like to remove the unique key that has been set on a column but it always returns an error at second line

The table tblprstatus has a field called PrStatus(unique key). I would like the Unique key removed but the field retained

I have tried

```
ALTER TABLE tblprstatus
DROP UNIQUE  PrStatus
```

But this always returns an error

Comment: using phpmyadmin ?

Comment: If it returns an error, please post what error it returns. Include all necessary information so we can help you properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First use

```
SHOW INDEX FROM tbl_name
```

to find out the name of the index. The name of the index is stored in the column called key_name in the results of that query.

Then you can use DROP INDEX:

```
DROP INDEX index_name ON tbl_name
```

replace index_name with your index and tbl_name with your table

or you can see this image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/enM7Y.png

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Alter table tblprstatus DROP index PrStatus;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!